# How can I delete empty arrays and after import to a sql database?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a text file that I read in php and split it in arrays.
After that i have a lot of arrays, and some of them are empty. How I delete these emty arrays and how I import the data in the mysql database?  Connect is all there.

```
//$DatabaseHost = "localhost"; 
//$DatabaseUser = "xx"; 
//$DatabasePassword = "xxx"; 
//$Database = "xxxx"; 
//$Table = "xxxx"; 

//******** Datenbank Connect ******** 

//$DatabaseConnect = mysql_connect($DatabaseHost, $DatabaseUser, $DatabasePassword) or die ("Keine Verbindung zum Server"); 
//$DatabaseSelect = mysql_select_db($Database, $DatabaseConnect) or die ("Die Datenbank gibt es nicht"); 


 $datei = file("daten/neuer0.txt"); 
foreach($datei AS $ausgabe) 
    { $zerlegen = explode(",", $ausgabe); } 

function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {

    $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
    $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
    return  $launch;
}
$text = $ausgabe;
{
$exploded = multiexplode(array(",",".","|",":","\"","\\",),$text);

print_r($exploded);
```

Comment: Please let us know, what you have tried so far.

Comment: It is better to asks different questions "How to delete empty arrays?" and "How to import data into mysql database" separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_filter and array_unique function to avoid the blank value for example,

```
$array = array("1" => "PHP code tester Sandbox Online",  
              "foo" => "bar", 5 , 5 => 89009, 
              "case" => "Random Stuff: " . rand(100,999),
              "PHP Version" => phpversion(),"bb"=>''
              );

  $get_final_dga_data=array_unique($array);
  $get_final_dga_data=array_filter($get_final_dga_data);
  print_r($get_final_dga_data);
```